# How do I add different class for my ordered lists

Tags: php

I want add `left, center & right` class to my ordered lists while loop.

Code

```
 <?php while ($fetch) { ?>
    <li>haha</li>
  <?php } ?>
```

Results should be

```
<ul>
  <li class="left">haha</li>
  <li class="center">haha</li>
  <li class="right">haha</li>
  <li class="left">haha</li>
  <li class="center">haha</li>
  <li class="right">haha</li>
</ul>
```

Let me know

Comment: Thanks +1! All answers working great.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
 <?php $classes = array("left","center","right");
    $i = 0;
    while ($fetch) { 
 ?>
    <li class="<?php echo $classes[$i++ % 3] ?>">haha</li>
  <?php } ?>
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$cnt=0;
while ($fetch)
{
  switch ($cnt%3)
  {
    case 0 : $class = 'left'; break;
    case 1 : $class = 'center'; break;
    case 2 : $class = 'right'; break;
  }
  echo '<li class="', $class, '">haha</li>';
  ++$cnt;
}
```

Comment: close, but not exactly. This will produce markup like `<lileft>haha</li>` and `<licenter>haha</li>`

Answer (score 1):

I've just tested the following code and verified that it produces the desired output:

```
<?php
$items = array('haha', 'haha', 'haha', 'haha', 'haha', 'haha');
$cssClasses = array('left', 'center', 'right');
echo "<ul>\n";
$i=0;
foreach ($items as $item) {
    echo "\t<li class=\"" . $cssClasses[$i++ % 3] . '">' . $item . "</li>\n";
}
echo "</ul>\n";
?>
```

The output is:

```
<ul>
    <li class="left">haha</li>
    <li class="center">haha</li>
    <li class="right">haha</li>
    <li class="left">haha</li>
    <li class="center">haha</li>
    <li class="right">haha</li>
</ul>
```